# TF30279: Plug-in with ID “Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Build” of type “Project Creation Plugins” could not be loaded

Tags: visual-studio-2019, tfs-2015

I am having a problem uploading Templates into Team Foundation 2015. This is happening with Templates that were created a while ago and have downloaded from the project collection. I then attempt to upload the template with no changes and I receive the following errors. Here is the log that gets generated. I have reinstalled Visual Studio with no success

```
2020-06-25T09:22:38 | Module: Engine | Thread: 11 | Starting process template validation
2020-06-25T09:22:38 | Module: Engine | The user identity information was retrieved from the Group Security Service | Completion time: 0.0009976 seconds
2020-06-25T09:22:38 | Module: Engine | Thread: 11 | Process template XML loaded
2020-06-25T09:22:38 | Module: Engine | Thread: 11 | Starting process template validation
---begin Exception entry---
Time: 2020-06-25T09:22:38
Module: Template Importer
Exception Message: TF30175: Process template validation failed (type ValidationFailedException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.EngineStarter.ValidateTemplate(DirectoryInfo templateDirectory)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.TemplateManagementService.ValidateMethodology(String folderPath, ILogHandler logHandler)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.TemplateManagementService.Import(String folderPath, ILogHandler logHandler)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: TF30279: Plug-in with ID "Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.Portal" of type "Project Creation Plugins" could not be loaded (type PluginNotFoundInCatalogException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.PluginHelper.ActivatePlugin[T](String type, String pluginId)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.PcwPlugin.get_PluginImplementation()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.GetProjectComponentInstance(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.GetShouldExecuteTask(Task task, IProjectComponentCreator& creator)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.ProjectCreationEngine.PerformAllTasks(ITaskPerformer taskPerformer, ProjectCreationContext creationContext, List`1 projectTasks)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.EngineStarter.RunEngine(Boolean isValidationRun, String templateFolder)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.PCW.EngineStarter.ValidateTemplate(DirectoryInfo templateDirectory)

--- end Exception entry ---
```

Answer (score 0):

Installed Visual Studio 2017 and used that version to upload the Templates. It worked.